# Adding Length dimension to a Crate Object

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns, constructor

Consider `Crate::addLength()` in the following code:

```
class Crate
{
    protected $length, $width, $height;

    function __construct(float $length, float $width, float $height)
    {
        $this->length = $length;
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
    }

    function addLength(float $length): Crate
    {
        return new self($this->length + $length, $this->width, $this->height);
    }
}
```

I am concerned that `Crate` object creating a `Crate` object is a violation of Single Responsibility Principle (SRP).  Crate object duties is to keep dimensions of the crate.  Creating another crate object seems like introducing extra responsibilities to a class that already has responsibilities.

With that in mind, how to I make the code better?

The directions I think I can go are

**1)  Is it better to just instead increase the length of the Crate?**

```
function addLength(float $length): void
{
    $this->length += $length;
}
```

When doing so however, my crate becomes 'stretchy', which is typically not done in real life.  Instead, a new crate is constructed with given measurements.

Thus,

**2) Is it better to instead delegate object creation to a separate class?**

```
class CrateService
{

    function addLength(Crate $crate, float $length): Crate
    {
        return new Crate($crate->GetLength() + $length, $crate->getWidth(), $crate->getHeight());
    }
}
```

That seems to work, even if a little cumbersome - we basically call every crate's dimension individually and add the adder length, and create a new crate.

Comment: The problem with this question is that we don't know if you're going to do other things with the `Crate` class. Set the color of the crate? Fill it with stuff? Who knows? You must have other plans for this class than just setting dimensions. Objects in a program don't always follow the same rules as objects in real-life. A 'stretchy' crate is not a problem, unless there's something else that prohibits it.

Comment: My plan is to 1) set up initial crate dimensions based on a pump product that will be in the crate, 2) if a motor is added to the pump (decided by customer), add a length adder to the crate's original length dimension.  I may later add a price computation based on crate dimensions to the `Crate` object.

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem, given your comment, to have a 'stretchy' crate, but in my example code below you can control whether the crate can be stretched or not.

```
class Crate
{
    private $length, $width, $height;
    private $resizable = true;

    function __construct(float $length, float $width, float $height)
    {
        list($this->length, $this->width, $this->height) = [$length, $width, $height];
    }

    function getDimensions(): array
    {
        return [$this->length, $this->width, $this->height];
    }

    function isResizable()
    {
        return $this->resizable;
    }

    function fixateSize()
    {
        $this->resizable = false;
    }

    function addLength(float $extraLength): float 
    {
        return $this->length += $this->isResizable() ? $extraLength : 0;
    }
}
```

I've added three methods; `getDimensions()`, `isResizable()` and `fixateSize()`. Note that there's no function to undo the `fixateSize()`. That is intentional: What would be the point of fixating the size if you can undo it?

I've made the dimension and resize fields `private`. Only the `Crate` class should be responsible for manipulating these. Child classes should use the methods of `Crate` to change them, hence the `getDimensions()` method.

Note how `addLength()` now returns the new length, and how it doesn't add the `$extraLength` when the crate size is fixated. Instead of returning the new length you could return a boolean, indicating whether the extra length is accepted. Another reason for not accepting the extra length could be that the crate would become too long.

I wouldn't use the `CrateService` class, that just overly complicated, and the `addLength()` method that returns a new object is just weird. The name of the method doesn't suggest this at all. A better name would have been `cloneAndStretch()`.

Comment: Thank you.  I have been reading about immutable objects in PHP (https://blog.joefallon.net/2015/08/immutable-objects-in-php/), and that is where I also get the concept and reasoning for making any changes in constructor only.  I am struggling with the immutability concept, however, debating on whether I actually need it or not.  The crate can be stretchy or not stretchy at code writing time (i.e. it will not change at runtime)